# Cypress test throws an error message when using an array

Tags: arrays, loops, cypress

In a cypress test case I use this line of code and cypress throws an error message that I do not understand. No idea what to do.
Any idea?
Any solution possible?

Code:

```js
const months = [
        'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'
      ];
  
      // Create an object to store the values dynamically
      const values = {};
  
      // Use a loop to iterate over each month
      months.forEach((month, index) => {
        cy.get('.tabele1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(1)').each(($e1, rowIndex, $list) => {
          var titletext = $e1.text();
          if (titletext.includes('Some Headline Text')) {
            cy.get(`.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(${index + 2})`).eq(rowIndex).then(function (amount) {
              // Dynamically store values in the object
              values[`valueMA_${month}1`] = amount.text().trim();
            });
          }
        });
      });

      // Example assertions in a loop
    months.forEach((month, index) => {
        expect (values[`valueMA_${month}1`]).to.equal('400');
    });
```

Cypress error message:

> AssertionError
> expected undefined to equal '400'

The error refers to this line of code:

```js
expect (values[`valueMA_${month}1`]).to.equal('400');
```

What is wrong with the code? I do not see it ...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move ,

`expect (values[valueMA_${month}1]).to.equal('400');`

Into your previous forEach() function, as below

`cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row3 > td:nth-child(${index + 2})).eq(rowIndex).then(function (amount) { expect(amount.text().trim()).to.equal('400'); });`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR**
The values can only be used after the `cy.get(...)` sequence has been run.

To do that, put the the second loop on the queue

```js
// executes on the queue
cy.then(() => {
  months.forEach((month, index) => {
    expect (values[`valueMA_${month}1`]).to.equal('400');
  })
})
```

---

**Full explanation**

Cypress runs the spec to see what `cy.get()` command you have, and adds them to the command queue, then it runs the command queue.

The second loop has ***no commands*** so Cypress runs it immediately, before it runs the command queue.

If you add `cy.then()` around the second loop, Cypress adds that whole block to the queue and executes it in the correct sequence.

It's kind of like a simple [Custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands)

If you want, you can also make a custom command

```js
const months = [...]
const values = {}

Cypress.Commands.add('verifyValues', (label) => {
  months.forEach((month, index) => {
    expect (values[`valueMA_${month}1`]).to.equal('400');
  })
})

...
// Use a loop to iterate over each month
months.forEach((month, index) => {
  cy.get(...)
  ...
})

// executes on the queue
cy.verifyValues()
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it like this:

```
const months = [
            'JAN', 'FEB', 'MAR', 'APR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'
          ];

const values = [];
    
// Use a loop to iterate over each month
        months.forEach((month, index) => {
            cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row1 > td:nth-child(1)').each(($e1, rowIndex, $list) => {
                var titletext=$e1.text()
                if (titletext.includes('Specific Headline Text')) {
                    cy.get('.table1 > tbody > tr.table_row1 > td:nth-child(' + (index +3) + ')').eq(rowIndex).then(function (amount) {
                        values[`valueMA_${month}1`] = amount.text().trim();
                        expect (values[`valueMA_${month}1`].toString()).to.equal('100');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```